# How to interpolate a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have the following data with me. The first row and the first column (highlighted) are two parameters for which the rest of the elements have been generated. I am hoping to convert this matrix into a 50 by 50 matrix, interpolating the data between the rows and column.

I have tried interpolating the second column in the following manner,

```
x=[100 300 500 700];
y=[-20 -184 -315.2 -412];
z = linspace(x(1),x(4),50);
yi=interp1(x,y,z,'cubic');
```

But, my problem is, I am not able to figure out how to interpolate with respect to the row simultaneously and get the entire matrix.

Any help/suggestion would be most welcome.

The data is given below;

```
    30  60  90
100 -20 -45 -80.5
300 -184    -215    -225.4
500 -315.2  -254    -339
700 -412    -419    -488
```

[image]

Comment: you meant `interp2`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri   yes, I know that interp2 is the function I should be using. But, I am not sure on how to use it. I am going through the documentation with no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is a function of two variables (`f(x,y)`) so you'll need to use [`interp2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) rather than `interp1`.

```
% Populate the data that you already have
rows =  [100, 300, 500 700];
cols = [30, 60, 90];

data = [-20      -45    -80.5
        -184    -215    -225.4
        -315.2  -254    -339
        -412    -419    -488];

% Interpolate this at 100 points in each direction
[newcols, newrows] = meshgrid(linspace(cols(1), cols(end)), ...
                              linspace(rows(1), rows(end)));

% Perform the bicubic interpolation
newdata = interp2(cols, rows, data, newcols, newrows, 'bicubic')
```